Find The Minimum Cycle Cutset of Icosahedron
My intuition is that a minimum cycle cutset of vertices must cover all "faces" and be spread out as much as possible. For an isogonal polyhedron, I guess it is $\lceil \frac{n}{k} \rceil$, where $n$ is the number of faces and $k$ is the number of edges of each face. Specifically, for an icosahedron, it should be $\lceil \frac{20}{3} \rceil = 7$. By the way, can this be thought of as finding a minimum vertex cover in the non-planar graph induced by "flattening" the polyhedron, hence making it NP-hard, or do the special properties of the graph provide a known, simple solution?
